# RNDIS driver crashes under Win 10 Pro but not on Win 10 home/student edition

Tags: windows, rndis

I have an application that requires an Ethernet protocol through a USB cable to control some device. All works under Win 7 using MS supplied RNDIS driver. My application also works under Win 10 Home or Student editions using an ACER supplied RNDIS driver, but not under Win 10 Pro. This might be because this application uses another network link (wireless) to access a database, and its Ethernet link could be in conflict with the wireless network through RNDIS driver under Win 10 Pro. How? What particular aspect of Win 10 Pro can cause this behavior and can we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: An updated and signed MS RNDIS driver can be obtained by contacting [Keynote Electronics](https://keynotephotonics.com/) to resolve the issues mentioned.